# Distance Between 2 Points in Matrix Form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$ \begin{bmatrix}-m_1 &1\\-m_2 &1\\ \vdots & \vdots\\-m_n &1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c_1\\ c_2\\ \vdots\\ c_n\end{bmatrix}  $$
and 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}-m_1 &1\\-m_2 &1\\ \vdots & \vdots\\-m_n &1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x} \\ \hat{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} c_1+\epsilon_1\\ c_2+\epsilon_2\\ \vdots\\ c_n+\epsilon_n\end{bmatrix}  $$
rewrite
$$ {\bf M}=\begin{bmatrix}-m_1 &1\\-m_2 &1\\ \vdots & \vdots\\-m_n &1\end{bmatrix} $$
and
$$ {\bf \epsilon}=\begin{bmatrix} \epsilon_1\\ \epsilon_2\\ \vdots\\ \epsilon_n\end{bmatrix} $$
I can get the difference is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}\hat{x} \\ \hat{y}\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}{\bf M}^T{\bf M}\end{bmatrix}^{-1}{\bf M}^T{\bf \epsilon} $$
How about the distance between the points in term of $ {\bf M}$,${\bf C}$, and ${\bf \epsilon}$ ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The distance between the points should just be the Euclidean norm $||[x,y]^T-[\hat{x},\hat{y}]^T||$.